# Python чтение текстового документа из вложенного файла

Tags: python

Есть папка, в которой много других папок, и в каждой из них по одному текстовому документу. Как сделать, чтобы он зашел в одну папку, прочитал текстовик, закрыл папку, перешел к следующей? Можно ли это сделать через glob.glob? Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью `glob`.
Например у нас есть:

```
$ tree test
test
├── a
│   └── 001.txt
└── b
    └── 001.txt
```

Чтобы прочитать все файлы с расширением txt в поддиректориях `test`:

```
import glob


for pathname in glob.glob('test/*/*.txt'):
    with open(pathname) as f:
        print(f.read(), end="")
```